# My ethernet is missing, how can i find it?

Tags: ethernet

COmcast was setting up an ethernet cable and there was no option to choose ethernet.  I have for years been using the stick from clear but wanted to go to cable for faster.  I currently am using a Wi-Fi router because that's all that I can get to work.  But where is the ethernet?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Click the + button on the bottom left, and select Ethernet from the menu to add it.